# Reading files from Django Apache2 after uploading it from site

Tags: django, apache2

When I try to read a file I uploaded from site i keep getting this error:

> IOError at /Project_details/h/add_file/ [Errno 13] Permission denied

The reason is there is no permission on new uploaded file to read or write. At least I believe that is the main problem.

I want the files I upload to automatically have permissions to read and write. I know about `chmod` commands but that's not useful in my case. I am using **Django 1.6**, **Postgresql** and **Apache2.4.7**.

Answer (score 0):

try to set **FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS** in settings.py:

```
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0644
```

as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#std:setting-FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS) in the django docs for version 1.6.